# Incompatible peer dependecy udpating angular material

Tags: angular, npm

i try to update angular material from v6 to v7 with the following command in my project:

```
npx @angular/cli@7 update @angular/material@7
```

This does not work due to some incompatible peer dependencies, e.g.:

```
Package "@kolkov/angular-editor" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/common" (requires ">=7.0.0 <8" (extended), would install "13.0.2").
```

But i don't understand where this comes from.

My project has in the dependencies of the package.json:

```
"@angular/common": "^7.2.16"
```

The peerDependencies of the "@kolkov/angular-editor" are defined as following:

```
"peerDependencies": {
"@angular/common": ">=7.0.0 <8",
"@angular/core": ">=7.0.0 <8",
"@angular/forms": ">=7.0.0 <8",
"@angular/platform-browser": ">=7.0.0 <8",
"rxjs": "^6.x.x"
```

}

Therefore this should be compatible. Why does the error message say "would install 13.0.2" and how can if fix this issue?

> "(requires ">=7.0.0 <8" (extended), would install "13.0.2")"

Comment: What version of "@kolkov/angular-editor" do you have in the package.json? it should be 0.18.4 and above - for Angular v7.x.x

Comment: Its @kolkov/angular-editor": "^0.18.4 , so it should be ok.